# Solving Differential Equation $4x^2yy'=3x(3y^2+2)+2(3y^2+2)^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I have tried the solve following differential equation with Riccati method but couldnt do.
Can someone help how can I find the particular solution if it is?

$$4x^2yy'=3x(3y^2+2)+2(3y^2+2)^3$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
$$4x^2yy'=3x(3y^2+2)+2(3y^2+2)^3$$
Substitute  $u=3y^2+2$

Then you have a Bernoulli's DE.
$$\dfrac 23x^2u'=3xu+2u^3$$

Comment: That's the nice way! +1

Comment: Thank you @Fakemistake